# .NET keyword "checked" conflicts with ExtJS MVC model Ext.tree.Panel "checked" field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs4, keyword, ext-direct

I'm using Sencha ExtJS 4 framework, and ExtDirect4DotNet server-side stack with ASP.NET.  I ran into an issue with the Sencha ExtJS MVC model functionality.

There is a standard field in the Ext.tree.Panel component, called "checked".  This is also a keyword in .NET.  It turns to a blue color in Visual Studio 2012.  Is there a way in Sencha to send a different value when the proxy sends JSON requests to the server?  I was thinking of overriding an event listener with some code to change it, but I'd rather use standard functionality if possible.

I'll +1 anything that works, and will accept the most standard functionality.

**Screen shot:**

[image]

Comment: That's the kind of problem you get when you use too many frameworks and pre-built stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@` character:

```
public bool @checked;
```